# Как убрать легенду у графиков qt QChart?

Tags: c++, qt

Как убрать легенду на графиках QChart?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пора учиться читать документацию...

```
chart->legend()->setVisible(false);
```